# MySQL Append-Only Model - Clean up query using DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Currently moving our tables over to an append only model to increase write performance by avoiding UPDATE and DELETE, with a memcached front end for SELECT's.

All rows are timestamped with the latest row being selected using MAX(timestamp).
This works well although after time the table will be full of old irrelevant data, we could write a simple

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE timestamp < XXXX
```

Although that will delete rows which may have not been updated in the last XX amount of time, and therefore remove that ID from the table completely not just old rows.

A very simple example schema and data to demonstrate is provided below

```
---------------------------
| id        |   INT       |
| name      |   VARCHAR   |
| timestamp |   TIMESTAMP |
---------------------------
```

Initial data

```
-------------------------------------------
| id        |   name       |  timestamp   |
-------------------------------------------
| 1         |   Trevor     |            1 |
| 2         |   Mike       |            1 |
-------------------------------------------
```

Should a users name be updated a row will be appended, not updated, with the users new name.

```
-------------------------------------------
| id        |   name       |  timestamp   |
-------------------------------------------
| 1         |   Trevor     |            1 |
| 2         |   Mike       |            1 |
| 1         |   Trev       |           60 |
-------------------------------------------
```

Using a simple DELETE query to remove rows older than 60 seconds (Real case would be more like an hour or even a day) would delete Trevor on row 1 as intended but it will also delete the only record of Mike.

```
-------------------------------------------
| id        |   name       |  timestamp   |
-------------------------------------------
| 1         |   Trev       |           60 |
-------------------------------------------
```

We need it to only DELETE distinct ID rows which are older than XX, so we would be left with both users even though Mike hasn't updated his name and his timestamp is older than XX amount of time.

```
-------------------------------------------
| id        |   name       |  timestamp   |
-------------------------------------------
| 2         |   Mike       |            1 |
| 1         |   Trev       |           60 |
-------------------------------------------
```

We could go through each ID, get the latest timestamp, then DELETE all rows older than that timestamp however as the table gets more users this process will take longer.

Is there any SQL query which could, preferably in one or 2 queries clean up the table as described above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on MySQL but I believe this query should do the trick:

```
DELETE t1 FROM
  table1 AS t1, table1 AS t2
WHERE 
  t1.id = t2.id
AND 
  t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp;
```

You could add those 60 minutes to t1.timestamp so it will only delete rows older than 60 minutes.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13963/1)